# How do I get the number of steps taken for this solution?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```js
function greatestNumber(array) {
    let highestValue = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(highestValue < array[i]){
            highestValue = array[i];
        }
    }
    return highestValue;
} 
let myArray = [5,1,23,4,55,2];
let output = greatestNumber(myArray);
console.log(output);
```

I am doing a coding exercise that requires me to rewrite a function to get O(N) time complexity. May I know what should I implement in my code to output the number of steps the function have taken to get the highestValue from the array?

I have tried initializing a variable called steps to 0 at the start and increment it in the for loop but that did not work.

Comment: your steps are obvious the length of the array. but you could save one step by taking the first item as start value and iterate from index `1`.

Comment: What do you mean by "but that did not work."? Have you tried debugging to monitor how your `steps` changed values?

Answer (score 0):

You already know the *number of steps taken for this solution*.

Since you're looping of `myArray` using `i < array.length`, the number of steps you took is `array.length`.

So you'll just need to alter your `console.log()` to include that info:

```
Highest number: 55
Number of steps: 6
```

```js
function greatestNumber(array) {
    let highestValue = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if (highestValue < array[i]){
            highestValue = array[i];
        }
    }
    return highestValue;
} 
let myArray = [5,1,23,4,55,2];
let output = greatestNumber(myArray);

console.log(`Highest number: ${output}\nNumber of steps: ${myArray.length}`);
```

---

As [Nina mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75520394/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-steps-taken-for-this-solution#comment133242705_75520394) in the comments, you can reduce the steps by 1 by starting on a value
(`highestValue = array[0]`), then you'll need to loop 1 less:

```
function greatestNumber(array) {
    let highestValue = array[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++)
        ....

console.log(`Highest number: ${output}\nNumber of steps: ${myArray.length - 1}`);
```

```
Highest number: 55
Number of steps: 5
```

```js
function greatestNumber(array) {
    let highestValue = array[0];
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++){
        if (highestValue < array[i]){
            highestValue = array[i];
        }
    }
    return highestValue;
} 
let myArray = [5,1,23,4,55,2];
let output = greatestNumber(myArray);

console.log(`Highest number: ${output}\nNumber of steps: ${myArray.length - 1}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can initialize a variable called steps at the start of the function and increment it using loop.

```js
function greatestNumber(array) {
    let highestValue = 0;
    let steps = 0; // Initialize steps to 0
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        steps++; // Increment steps in each iteration
        if(highestValue < array[i]){
            highestValue = array[i];
        }
    }
    console.log("Number of steps taken: " + steps); // Output number of steps
    return highestValue;
} 

let myArray = [5,1,23,4,55,2];
let output = greatestNumber(myArray);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: `steps = array.length` would provide the same result in your case.